# $\operatorname{rank}(A\in M_{m\times n}(F)) =m \implies \exists~B\in M_{n\times m}(F)$ s.t. $AB=I_m$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $A ∈ M_{m×n}(F)$ be a matrix with $\operatorname{rank}(A) = m$. I just need some help showing that there exists a matrix $B ∈ M_{n×m}(F)$ such that $AB = I_m$.

Comment: $(l\times m)\cdot(m\times n)=(l\times n) \implies (m\times n)\cdot(n\times m)=(m\times m)$

Comment: @Jyrki What kind of people read John von Neumann?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: By a well known theorem the column rank of $A$ is then also equal to $m$. Therefore you can write the column vector $e^{(j)}$ number $j$ of $I_m$ as a linear combination
$e^{(j)}=\sum_{i=1}^n b_{ij}A^{(i)}$ of the $n$ columns $A^{(i)}, i=1,2,\ldots, n$ of $A$.

Comment: Are your $n$'s and $m$'s right?

Comment: I think so. ${}{}$

Comment: This is essentially the answer then.

Comment: Yes. Sorry about ruining it for you. I first posted a version without the $b_{ij}$:s spelled out, but then I thought that it was too vague. Sometime hard to strike a good balance. Do make sure that you understand, why taking linear combinations of columns amounts to multiplying a given matrix by another matrix from the right.

Comment: OK, thank you, Jyrki.